# Julia: Dictionary with Tuple keys containing Composite Types

Tags: julia

I ran into an issue trying to using a dictionary whose keys are a tuple including a composite type.

Here is a minimal example to replicate my issue:

```
import Base: hash, isequal    

type T
    a :: Int
    b :: Int
end

function isequal(A::(T,Int), B::(T,Int))
    A[1].a == B[1].a && A[1].b == B[1].b && A[2] == B[2]
end
function hash(A::(T,Int))
    hash(A[1].a + A[1].b + A[2])
end

d = Dict{(T,Int),Int}()

d[(T(1,1),1)] = 1
d[(T(2,2),2)] = 2

r = (T(2,2),2)

for k in keys(d)
    println(isequal(r, k) && hash(r) == hash(k))
end
println(d[r])
```

Running this results in:

```
false
true
ERROR: key not found: (T(2,2),2)
```

So `isequal` and `hash` work, but for some reason the dict is not.

Does anyone know what is going on? Thank you.

Comment: I added some print statements to `isequal` and `hash`. For some reason adding to the dict causes it to call `isequal` (why not hash?) and checking the dict with `d[r]` does not cause either to be called.

Comment: hash and isequal should be imported for them to be overloaded. the import statement is not in the snippet (and it is in Iain's below). Does this explain the difference?

Comment: You are correct that they need to be imported. I did have that but should have put it there. I will add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something I don't quite understand in this case about the types of tuples and dispatching, but basically [you need to implement the two argument form of `hash` for this case](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=hash#Base.hash). The following very similar code works as expected, as a point of comparison, without the two argument form:

```
type T
    a::Int
    b::Int
end

function Base.isequal(A::T, B::T)
    println("isequal", A, " ", B)
    A.a == B.a && A.b == B.b
end
function Base.hash(A::T)
    println("hash", A)
    hash(A.a + A.b)
end

d = Dict{T,Int}()

d[T(1,1)] = 1
d[T(2,2)] = 2

println("test")
r = T(2,2)
println(d[r])
```

with output

```
isequalT(1,1) T(1,1)
hashT(1,1)
isequalT(2,2) T(2,2)
hashT(2,2)
test
hashT(2,2)
isequalT(2,2) T(2,2)
2
```

Comment: Interesting. I am on Version 0.3.1 (2014-09-21 21:30 UTC)

Comment: Note that you ran it with dict where the keys are type T. My example has a dict where the keys are tuples: (T,Int). Can you try running that?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that I can recreate your problem, and that the problem doesn't occur with this very similar example. My point is that I think you should file a JuliaLang/julia issue. I've edited my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by creating `hash` & `isequal` functions for each composite type rather than for the overall tuple.

If you key is `(T,Int)`:

Instead of this:

```
function isequal(A::(T,Int), B::(T,Int))
    A[1].a == B[1].a && A[1].b == B[1].b && A[2] == B[2]
end
function hash(A::(T,Int))
    hash(A[1].a + A[1].b + A[2])
end
```

Do this:

```
function isequal(A::T, B::T)
    A.a == B.a && A.b == B.b
end
function hash(A::T)
    hash(A.a + A.b)
end
```

If you want the original formulation to work, you have to specify Base.hash with the optional second argument: `h::Uint64`:

```
function isequal(A::(T,Int), B::(T,Int))
    A[1].a == B[1].a && A[1].b == B[1].b && A[2] == B[2]
end
function hash(A::(T,Int))
    hash(A[1].a + A[1].b + A[2])
end
function hash(A::(T,Int), h::Uint64)
    hash(A[1].a + A[1].b + A[2] + h)
end
```

Comment: I don't see why the version in your original question shouldn't work though?

Comment: I just stumbled onto the correct solution: it turns out you have to implement hash to support the optional second argument `h::Uint64`. Not sure why this necessarily fixes it but it does.

Comment: Great point, and thats documented actually here: http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=hash#Base.hash. I've updated my answer too.